# How to crop an image with CSS using width, height, x and y axis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am creating a cropping feature with react-easy-crop. I will save the user's image along
with pixel coordinates for their cropping preference.

*What I am trying to do is use react-easy-crops parameters to crop the banner image to be displayed on a user profile.*

react-easy-crop which uses react-image-crop yields the following parameters:

```
{ width: integer, height: integer, x: integer, y: integer }
```

**With CSS**

How would I use THIS data to render a cropped image in CSS?

(I know there are ways to crop with CSS, but I am trying to use the above data.)

**With Javascript**

I have attempted to convert the Image URL into a blob or base64 to apply cropping, but I run into CORS errors as the image is from Azure blob. I would prefer a CSS solution rather than delving into security matters.

Comment: you could probably dig into object-fit and object-position  take a look at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: It depends a bit on what you want to do with the image. For example, is it to be used alongside other CSS relating to an element, such as object-fit or background-size contain or cover?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here 2 articles I found.

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-cropping-images-object-fit
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp
- https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-change-image-size-in-css

As far as I have researched, you cannot do that (width and height with CSS). The only way possible is by doing this:

```
<img src="assets/images/image.png" width="50" height="50">
```

As G-Cyrillus said, you can use the `object-fit` property.

And for X and Y, the best shot you have that I know of is using `padding-left: 5px` and `margin-left: 5px`. Margin is for the outside and padding for the inside I believe.

Hope this helps and happy coding!